# Cannot install Ubuntu 12 on Windows 8 machine with UEFI

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a windows 8 machine, but I'm unable to do it. After the point where the installation checks if I have enough space, an internet connection, a check box for updating the system during installation, etc, the comes the point where I need to choose a partition where to install.

The thing is that at this point, as there is no partition available (it's completely blank .. absolutely nothing in it), I try to add anything to the screen in order to add a new partition, but I'm unable to do it.

This has never happened to me before, so I have no idea as to how to proceed in order to install Ubuntu on this machine.

PS: Tried searching google but couldn't find a problem that matched my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Ubuntu installer is detecting your disk but claiming it has no partitions, then that likely means one of two things:

- Your partition table is damaged (or at least, the libparted library doesn't like your partition table). This is essentially a bug in libparted.
- The disk is configured as part of a motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID") array, but you're not using it as such in Linux.

The first issue seems to be more common, based on reports I've seen. A very common cause is that a GPT disk is repartitioned in Windows to use MBR instead. The result is a legal MBR disk, but with leftover remnants of GPT data. The problem is that libparted detects the leftover GPT data and becomes confused. This situation is becoming common because people re-install Windows 8 or install Windows 7 over Windows 8, often switching from EFI-mode booting to BIOS-mode booting in the process. Because Windows ties partition table type to boot mode (BIOS/MBR, EFI/GPT), this results in a change in the partition table, too. If this is the cause of your problem, it can be fixed by running [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) on the disk. The same program can fix some other common problems, too, but I can't guarantee that it will fix your problem. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/) for more on this issue.

Comment: Hello. You are right in all your assumptions of my problem. But, with the help of a friend, we managed to fix the problem another way. Granted it isn't as good as your way, but it worked

Comment: We ran ubuntu from the USB pendrive. We listed all partitions and manually removed every single one of them. This wasn't a problem for me because I didn't want windows 8

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote you, but I onlu have 8 points and I need 15 of reputation to upvote :(